# Google Maps Android API v2 'Couldn't get connection factory client'

Tags: android, google-maps

I tried a lot to get the google map in the Android App. For me it seems that the Api-Key is not recognized correct.

My key build:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore MyUser\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

used to get the API-Key for Android Apps with the given package-name.

The Manifest-file is set with the maps-library and internet permission.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

After all starting the App at Tab2 i get further an error and the map isn't loaded:

```
MapActivity   Handling network change notification: CONNECTED
MapActivity   Couldn't get connection factory client
```

I'm stumped, has someone a solution?

Comment: Have you setup everything required in the `API console?`

Comment: it is more than 2 permissions in Manifest you need to add. i'll look it up

Comment: <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />    <-- this one is only valid for maps-v1. you need to search for GooglePlayService-library as it includes the maps-library now!!

Answer (score 1):

in Manifest i got for the google-maps v2:

```
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<permission
        android:name="com.xxx.salesapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.salesapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
               android:value="AIzaSy******************A"/>
```

though im not sure which of the two MAPS_RECEIVE permissions belong to v1 or v2

Comment: i compared mine with yours. if you have entered an android-google-maps-v2-key, then the manifest shoudln't be the source of your problem

Comment: what does your logcat say?